# Enable logging for OpenOffice daemon sOffice.bin

Tags: linux, openoffice

We have problems converting a document with the openoffice daemon sOffice.bin. Where can I find / enable logfiles for this process?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it myself, but maybe building a "[Non Product Build](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Non_Product_Build)" with extended debugging options would be helpful. See also the "[Debugging](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Debugging)" chapter of OOo Wiki.